# Question on an algorithm picking assignments for employees

Tags: standard-deviation, algorithms

I have the following problem. I have X people that, on a weekly basis, will pick assignments out of Y different assignments. Each assignment has a different difficulty score, so at the end of each week each person has a calculated score.

Each week, the previous scores are added to the current week's.

Once an employee picks an assignment, his score is recalculated.

If, on Sunday, any of assignments is left unassigned, it's assigned automatically starting from the persons with the lowest scores.

After running the algorithm for a few weeks, I notice that the most consistent employees will pick many assignments, where the least consistent ones will pick less or none, so there's a big standard deviation between the scores.

Now I've set it so people in the top 20 of the board are not allowed to pick assignments for the current week, so the lower-score employees are forced to pick more (or the algorithm will put them automatically on Sunday).

The question is, what's the way to determine the best top X number to estimate based on the current score board (the 20 I placed is arbitrary)? I mean, given the score table of the employees, how many should be excluded from picking an assignment each week so the score board will be eventually balanced?